# Quemar etiqueta [errores]

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, etiquetas, solicitud-de-quemado

Hay hasta el momento [59 preguntas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/errores) en la etiqueta [errores](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/errores)

O sino, volvamos a crear una llamada [programación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/programaci%c3%b3n) :D

ahora enserio... esta etiqueta no sirve para nada. Habria que ponerla en la lista negra.

Comment: Me parece bien. ¿No se usa para nada más que un error de compilación/ejecución? (normalmente la veo y no le presto atención).

Comment: a la hoguera con ella

Comment: Sin duda, hay que erradicarla. Es como poner una etiqueta que sea `pregunta`.

Comment: Esa etiqueta la creó cierto usuario que se la pasa modificando preguntas añadiendo etiquetas erróneas .-.

Comment: ¿Podría ponerse como sinónimo de `control-de-errores` (`error-handling`)?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster El problema es que los usuarios la están usando para cualquier cosas, eso va seguir pasando. No debe haber ambigüedades en cuanto a para que debe usarse la etiqueta.

Comment: @rnd lo se, por eso la solución es o bien eliminar la etiqueta (tu propuesta) o darle un significado no ambiguo (mi propuesta). La *ventaja* de mi propuesta es que al añadir `errores` el usuario podrá ver la descripción y (con suerte) *deducir* que no es la etiqueta que busca.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster quiza no me explique bien; aunque la hagamos sinónimo, son pocos los usuarios que leen la orientación de uso (sobre todo nuevos) y acabara en preguntas sin relación o generando trabajo extra editando las preguntas para remover la etiqueta. La etiqueta en si debe ser auto descriptiva. Por eso las etiquetas que sirven son o el nombre de una tecnología o una técnica o un algoritmo, etc.

Comment: @rnd el *trabajo extra* ya lo tenemos, tanto si la etiqueta es eliminada como si se usa de sinónimo se podrá seguir usando mal; con la diferencia que como sinónimo puede reducir (mucho o poco) el uso incorrecto al tener una descripción, mientras que una etiqueta inexistente no tiene descripción alguna... *essolomiopinión*

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster si se pone en la lista negra, no seria el caso.

Comment: @rnd no conocía la existencia de la "lista negra" de etiquetas y no se cómo funciona pero puedo hacerme una idea, entiendo mejor tu propuesta y la aplaudo, mas sigo pensando que también es evaluable mi otro punto de vista :)

Comment: Yo apoyo la idea de @PaperBirdMaster  `control-de-errores` seria un nombre mas ideal para ejemplificar lo que se quiere, pero de momento hay que mandar a lista negra `errores`

Comment: De hecho no sabía que se usaba mucho esta etiqueta, **hay que banear el tag "errores"**!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Se ha quemado la etiqueta `ERRORES` en una ceremonia con poca asistencia. ;)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: moraleja: debo entrar más seguido a META.es.stackoverflow.com

Comment: en paz descanse.