# La etiqueta [error] se ha quemado

Tags: soporte, estado-completado, etiquetas, solicitud-de-quemado, solicitud-de-lista-negra

> Solicitud de quemado completada. <sub>(véase [¿Cuál es el proceso para eliminar las etiquetas (quemarlas)?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2839/83))</sub>

## Propuesta original

Quizás algunos recuerden la etiqueta `[errores]`, que fue [quemada en una ceremonia con poca asistencia](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1134/127) y [twitteada sin retweets](https://twitter.com/esStackOverflow/status/804444714917240833).

Bueno, parece que renació de las cenizas, con menos fuerza... en singular.

- Hay 45 preguntas etiquetadas [error](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/error)

*Esto es una batalla entre el bien y el mal. Es una cántica de Dante en el noveno círculo del infierno. Es una reaparición impertinente salida del oficio del Quijote.*

### Debemos quemar la etiqueta [error](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/error).

*-Que la fuerza los acompañe.*

> Eventos que se fueron sucediendo
>
> - 25/4/17 - Se eliminó la etiqueta de todas las preguntas para poder quemarla.
> - 11/06/17 - Volvió a renacer de las cenizas. Volví a editar para eliminarla de 3 preguntas.
> - 2/11/17 - Dejamos de revisar por unos meses, y ya hay **48 preguntas** con esta etiqueta...
> - 17/11/17 - Esta vez seguimos sin eliminarlas. 64 preguntas y contando.
> - 27/02/18 - 108 preguntas... y contando.
>
> ---
>
> - > **Tengo una diferencia de opinión en el tema de quemado**
>   >
>   > Independientemente de si hay o no al momento en que sea evaluado si se quema o no, es importante **prohibirla** para aliviarle un poco la
>   >     carga a las personas que le dedican tiempo limpiando un poco el sitio.
>   >     Vamos, es sencillo, se agrega en el blacklist y tema terminado! Esto
>   >     no es un tema a discutir de si corresponde o no, es obvio que no hay
>   >     que permitir meta-etiquetas como esta. ¿Podemos pedir un par de
>   >     minutos de recursos del equipo de SO para que no haya que estar
>   >     editando esto todo el tiempo? Además, cuando un usuario intenta usarla
>   >     y ve el mensaje de que es una etiqueta prohibida, está aprendiendo a
>   >     usar el sitio.

Comment: Es como si fuera parte de la fuerza oscura que se esconde detrás de Mordor. Debe ser quemada al igual que el anillo de poder.

Comment: En este momento hay 51 preguntas con [tag:error]

Comment: Ya sólo quedan 29 :)

Comment: que implica quemar? se borra de todas las preguntas y se prohibe el uso por medio del sistema, o no?

Comment: @Mariano no hay un bot que haga eso? .... casa de herrero, programa de palo :P (digo cuchara )

Comment: Y ya hay 3 más :O

Comment: ¿A quién hay que llamar la atención para que se corrija esto? Está empeorando bastante últimamente. Los moderadores no pueden hacerlo, ¿cierto?

Comment: Por qué es mal recibido poner la etiqueta "error"?

Comment: _0 preguntas con etiquetas error_ ahora mismo en [tag:error]. Luego esto está [meta-tag:estado-completado], ¡enhorabuena a todos!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Observaciones/Guía para re-etiquetar:

La etiqueta [error](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/error) normalmente puede eliminarse de una pregunta sin que altere el significado o el alcance de la misma. No obstante, esta etiqueta está aplicada particularmente a preguntas que pueden estar cerca del umbral de baja calidad o que pueden ser cerradas. Por favor prestad especial atención a esto, para proceder debidamente con cada una de las preguntas.

**Chat**: Creé la sala de chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74490/quemando-error.
No creo que sea totalmente necesario en este caso, pero sirve ante cualquier duda.

## Progreso:

La etiqueta [error](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/error) está en proceso de ser quemada. <strike>Puedes ayudar al revisar otras preguntas con esta etiqueta y...</strike> Ya se editaron todas las preguntas que tenían esta etiqueta, quedando solamente las preguntas cerradas.

- **editar** preguntas (para mejorar la pregunta *y* eliminar la etiqueta),
- **reportar/cerrar** preguntas que son duplicados/fuera de tema/no claras/demasiado amplias/basadas en opiniones,
- filtrando en esta etiqueta en la [Cola de votos de cierre](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/close),
- **votar** en preguntas con esta etiqueta,
- votar para **eliminar** las preguntas con esta etiqueta (después de que se hayan cerrado, pero solamente si la Pregunta/Respuesta no contiene nada de valor)

Algunos enlaces para ayudar en este proceso:

- [Abiertas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Berror%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Cerradas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Berror%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Sin respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Berror%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [Sin respuesta aceptada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Berror%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## ¡Recuerden que el quemado es un esfuerzo de limpieza!

#### Rescaten lo que se pueda en donde sea posible al editar y re-etiquetar.

No queremos destruir al azar, así que rescatar las publicaciones debe ser la primera prioridad. Si una pregunta puede ser salvada, por favor edítala. Esa edición deberá mejorar *todos* los problemas con la pregunta *y* eliminar la etiqueta [error](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/error), al reemplazarla con otra (si fuese necesario), como se describe anteriormente.

#### Preguntas que no se pueden salvar deben ser reportadas/cerradas. No necesitan ser re-etiquetadas.

Si la pregunta no es apropiada para este sitio, no te preocupes sobre si debes o no eliminar la etiqueta [error](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/error). Simplemente repórtala/ciérrala tal cual está.

Al final del proceso de quemado, todas las preguntas que queden con la etiqueta [error](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/error) deben estar cerradas. Se eliminarán en grupo, cosa que quitará la etiqueta del sistema automáticamente con distracciones mínimas.

#### Pide ayuda si lo necesitas (comentando acá o en el [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74490/quemando-error)).

---

## Texto de ayuda (como guía para quienes usen la etiqueta)

g3rv4 ofreció agregarle un texto de ayuda que aparezca como notificación cuando se intenta utilizar.

El texto de esta advertencia se publicó en [¿Podríamos tener un pequeño detector de publicaciones en inglés que notificara a los autores?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2043/127)

Comment: A por ello. Con un poco de suerte, esto lo limpiamos en un rato

Comment: ¿Un texto del tipo así? _Esta etiqueta no está permitida. Intenta describir tu problema de una forma más específica, añadiendo etiquetas sobre la tecnología en la que estos errores ocurren_.

Comment: @fedorqui Tal cual. Está el ejemplo reciente de [¿Algún “malvado” que ponga a \[google\] en la lista negra?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3269/127) (con captura de pantalla)... Agregá lo que quieras en esta publicación y vamos editando y comentando sobre eso.

Comment: @Pikoh exactamente lo que pensé... pero se me acumularon demasiadas cosas pendientes de MSOes y quiero empezar a liquidarlos hoy con un poco de ayuda... Esta etiqueta no requiere pensar mucho. La mayoría de las preguntas están bien etiquetadas y tienen solamente un pequeño `[error]` :-)

Comment: @Mariano creo que el proceso está completo casi al 100%, a falta de algunas que deben ser cerradas...

Comment: @Pikoh casi todo tuyo! Genio! Estoy votando para cierre las que voy encontrando :-)

Comment: @fedorqui finalmente puse la descripción para la notificación.