# Eliminar etiqueta [crash]

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, etiquetas, solicitud-de-quemado

Deseo proponer que eliminemos la etiqueta [crash](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/crash) del sitio Stack Overflow en español.

- Solamente hay 7 preguntas bajo esta etiqueta.
- No tiene wiki (no veo porqué habria de tenerla, pero de todos modos
  lo menciono)
- Las preguntas con esta etiqueta no tienen ninguna relación unas con
  otras

Hace unos meses se quemo la etiqueta [error](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/error) y creo que, básicamente, es la misma etiqueta, pero en inglés.

---

Relacionado: [Quemar etiqueta [error]](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1738/quemar-etiqueta-error?rq=1)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Si por favor.

Ya la había visto rondando por ahí, pero por la euforia de las elecciones se me paso hacer algo al respecto.

En este momento la removí de las 7 preguntas que la tenían, ahora se ejecutara un proceso diario que la borrara.

Si un mod nos ayuda a bloquearla para siempre...

Comment: No es algo que pueda hacer un moderador, pero para tan pocas preguntas, no creo que haga falta hacer más que lo que hiciste, esperemos que no vuelva a aparecer. Gracias por eliminarla

Comment: @Mariano pero se supone que hay una lista negra no?

Comment: sí, claro. Pero la idea es que se use sólo para casos extremos con etiquetas que son recurrentes. La verdad, no me imagino que [TAG:crash] sea tan común como para que sigan utilizándola después de que se elimine... Los moderadores no pueden ponerla en lista negra, sólo empleados.

Comment: @Mariano ohhhhhhhhhhhhhhh, pensaba que si, muchas gracias por la info. Simpre podemos contar  contigo

Comment: igual, lo de que no es recurrente, es solo mi opinión... Quizás sigue apareciendo en el futuro y ahí podemos que la quemen... Yo suelo detalle un comentario al primero que crea este tipo etiquetas, referenciado la info de no crear meta etiquetas