# Añadir una nueva etiqueta con pocas preguntas

Tags: discusión, etiquetas

Hace días estuve revisando una pregunta que trataba sobre VHDL y me encontré que un usuario colocó de etiqueta [python] cuando no se trataba código relacionado y el motivo fue porque no existía la etiqueta [vhdl] (la edición fue siguiente: https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/394201/revisions).

Me encontré otras 3 preguntas en donde sucedía lo mismo y decidí añadir la etiqueta en estas.

A partir de allí, decidí crear una nueva etiqueta con un poco de explicación sobre VHDL e indicó que iba a ser revisada por pares (al no tener suficientes privilegios).

Tengo las siguientes dudas:

- ¿Es correcto haber editado las preguntas y añadir esta etiqueta (aunque no exista)?
- ¿Es correcto crear una nueva etiqueta para un lenguaje que es más bien de descripción?
- ¿Es correcto crear una nueva etiqueta cuando solo hay cuatro preguntas en el sitio relacionadas con esta? (entiendo que en un futuro pueden surgir más). Esta tercera duda surge porque veo que se deciden eliminar etiquetas cuando tienen pocas preguntas (e.g [Eliminar etiqueta [crash]](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2630/eliminar-etiqueta-crash)).

Saludos.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A todo, la respuesta es si.

Si camina en dos patas, tiene un pico y hace cuack, seguro es un pato...

Si la forma de describir las herramientas es usando un lenguaje, y se puede "programar" entonces definitivamente (en mi opinion) es el lugar correcto...

UML no es un lenguaje.. es una descripcion de un sistema, y sin embargo tenemos esa etiqueta.

Asi que (De mi parte) gracias por tomarte el trabajo de arreglar esas preguntas.

Y por las dudas, las etiquetas ya estan creadas y aprobadas, no dudes en modificar otras preguntas si el cambio es pertinente...

Comment: Esto resuelve mis dudas. Muchas gracias por tu respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

Según mi punto de vista:

¿Es correcto haber editado las preguntas y añadir esta etiqueta (aunque no exista)?

- Es correcto agregar etiquetas apropiadas y eliminar las que no correspondan, sin embargo, creo que deben existir previamente

¿Es correcto crear una nueva etiqueta para un lenguaje que es más bien de descripción?

- Viendo los resultados que arroja Google para [*VHDL*](https://www.google.com.mx/search?q=vhdl), me parece que la etiqueta sí es apropiado crearla

¿Es correcto crear una nueva etiqueta cuando solo hay cuatro preguntas en el sitio relacionadas con esta? (entiendo que en un futuro pueden surgir más).

- No creo que la existencia de etiquetas deba depender de la cantidad de preguntas, sino del uso que se les pueda dar y que realmente sean aplicables en programación

Esta tercera duda surge porque veo que se deciden eliminar etiquetas cuando tienen pocas preguntas (e.g Eliminar etiqueta [crash]).

- El ejemplo que pones de eliminar la etiqueta `crash` es muy específico, porque es una palabra en inglés y no representa un tema específico de programación
- Continuando con el punto anterior, sabemos que cualquier programa puede fallar, pero incluir etiquetas como `crash`, `error` u otras genéricas, no ayuda a determinar la causa del error
- Otro ejemplo es el que expone @PabloLozano en [esta pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4331/eliminemos-la-etiqueta-javascript-objeto), donde la etiqueta puede ser origen de confusiones

Comment: Muchas gracias, @Triby. Me habéis solventado las dudas.