# Las 50 etiquetas más usadas que no tienen descripción de uso

Tags: discusión

¿Cuáles serían las 50 etiquetas más usadas en el sitio que no poseen descripción de uso?

La idea es que nos animemos a completar esa información, dotando a aquellas etiquetas más usadas y quizá queridas por nosotros, de una adecuada descripción.

Comment: Me parece una buena iniciativa,enhorabuena.

Answer (score 7):

Con la siguiente consulta que he creado en Data Stackexchange: [Top 50 most used tags without Wiki description / 50 etiquetas más usadas sin descripción Wiki](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/784105/top-50-most-used-tags-without-wiki-description-50-etiquetas-mas-usadas-sin-desc) podemos obtener las 50 etiquetas más usadas que no tienen descripción de uso.

Esta respuesta está marcada como Wiki de Comunidad, para que podamos quizá ir tachando las etiquetas a las que alguno de nosotros se decida a dotar de una descripción de uso... o bien para actualizar esta lista más adelante.

En la consulta de Data Stackexchange he dejado comentado el código que generaría una lista que se puede pegar automáticamente, como ocurre ahora.

He aquí la lista al día de hoy.

¡Vamos a animarnos a dotar a alguna de estas etiquetas de su descripción!

Como nota adicional, actualmente hay 628 etiquetas que no tienen descripción de uso.

### 50 etiquetas más usadas sin descripción de uso

- Fecha: 17 de enero de 2018
- Total general de etiquetas sin descripción a la fecha: **628**

  ---

  - [select](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/select)
  - [error](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/error)
  - [react](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/react)
  - [if](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/if)
  - [fragment](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/fragment)
  - [checkbox](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/checkbox)
  - [php5](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/php5)
  - [eloquent](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/eloquent)
  - [list](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/list)
  - [while](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/while)
  - [bootstrap-3](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/bootstrap-3)
  - [ionic-framework](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/ionic-framework)
  - [input](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/input)
  - [ionic3](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/ionic3)
  - [video](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/video)
  - [spinner](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/spinner)
  - [sql-server-2012](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/sql-server-2012)
  - [random](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/random)
  - [datatable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/datatable)
  - [insert](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/insert)
  - [servidor](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/servidor)
  - [terminal](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/terminal)
  - [calendar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/calendar)
  - [ireport](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/ireport)
  - [formato](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/formato)
  - [apache2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/apache2)
  - [php7](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/php7)
  - [file](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/file)
  - [textview](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/textview)
  - [path](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/path)
  - [sesiones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/sesiones)
  - [sql-server-2014](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/sql-server-2014)
  - [function](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/function)
  - [diccionarios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/diccionarios)
  - [edittext](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/edittext)
  - [flexbox](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/flexbox)
  - [composer](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/composer)
  - [cámara](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/c%C3%A1mara)
  - [estructuras](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/estructuras)
  - [nullpointerexception](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/nullpointerexception)
  - [tabla-dinámica](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/tabla-din%C3%A1mica)
  - [wordpress-plugin](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/wordpress-plugin)
  - [google-maps-v3](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/google-maps-v3)
  - [model](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/model)
  - [http-post](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/http-post)
  - [struct](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/struct)
  - [compilar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/compilar)
  - [pyqt4](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/pyqt4)
  - [rutas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/rutas)
  - [upload](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/upload)

Comment: ¿La etiqueta [tag:error] no se había quemado?

Comment: @blonfu no parece. Ahí está, viva y coleando.

Comment: es una linda lista de etiquetas a quemar... ;) hay que revisar una por una si algunas tienen sentido..

Comment: select y error.. son dos etiquetas que no deberian existir.. no se si les vamos a poner descripcion.. o a matar la mayoria.. igual es una buena iniciativa...

Comment: Pues también @gbianchi . La verdad es que me sorprendió que ciertas etiquetas tan raras tengan tanto uso, como `cámara`, `rutas`, `upload`. Están ente las 50 más usadas de SO en español.

Comment: En beta no era tan dificil crear etiquetas... y ahi quedaron. Y muchoa usuarioa no saben etiquetar correctamente... si ves las preguntas sobre select vas a ver q es casi imposible ponerle descripcion.. la usan para cualquier cosa...

Comment: @gbianchi la lista y la query de Data Stackexchange podría ser interesante para hacer revisiones en ese sentido y mejorar ese aspecto del sitio. De todos modos, de la lista podemos sacar etiquetas importantes que no cuentan con descripción.

Comment: @A.Cedano no están entre las 50 más usadas en Stack Overflow en español. Esas son las 50 etiquetas sin descripción más usadas. [tag:select], que es la que más preguntas tiene, es la #150 del sitio (no se encuentra hasta la quinta página de etiquetas).

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro, es precisamente lo que he dicho: En el título de la pregunta: **50 etiquetas más usadas que no tienen descripción de uso**, en la respuesta: **50 etiquetas más usadas sin descripción de uso**, o lo que es lo mismo: **50 etiquetas sin descripción de uso más usadas**. No me refiero a **todas** las etiquetas, sino a las más usadas y que no tienen descripción.

Comment: @blonfu No. Publicada hace 9 meses, y editada varias veces para llamar la atención -> https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1738/127

Comment: @Mariano esa etiqueta se comporta como un `error` o como un `virus` :-) , o sea que cuando se creía que ya todo andaba bien, reaparece y ahí la tienes, número 2 dentro del género aquí tratado. ¡Y pisándole los pies a la número 1 según la consulta !

Comment: @Mariano me refiero a la limpieza que se hizo... Y al hecho de que sea casi la más usada en este género después de eso. Por cierto, ¿Quemarla significa que ya nadie podría crearla de nuevo?

Comment: @A.Cedano para responder correctamente, ponerla en lista negra implica que no se pueda volver a usar (quemarla es simplemente eliminarla de todas las preguntas). Sin embargo, cuando nos referimos a quemarla, estamos dejando implícito que es quemar + agregar a lista negra

Comment: **if** debería estar como etiqueta?

Comment: @iuninefrendor quizás lo mejor para `if` sería la etiqueta [tag:condiciones] (aunque sigue pareciendo algo genérica como etiqueta)