# Quemar etiqueta [error] (solicitud según proceso oficial)

Tags: soporte, solicitud-de-quemado

Esta solicitud tiene como antecedente [Quemar etiqueta [error]](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1738/65). En síntesis en varias ocasiones se ha eliminado la etiqueta del sitio pero vuelve a aparecer una y otra vez.

A continuación el tamiz de las cuatro preguntas para la evaluación de las propuestas de quemado de una etiqueta.

**1. ¿Describe el contenido de las preguntas en donde es aplicada la etiqueta? ¿Es clara?**

No es clara ya que hay muchísimos tipos de errores relacionados y ajenos a la temática del sitio.

**2.  ¿Se encuentra el concepto en conformidad con el tema de la comunidad?**

El concepto es demasiado amplio puede aplicar a casi cualquier cosa.

**3. ¿Añade la etiqueta algún contenido valioso a la aportación?**

No añade ningún contenido valioso.

**4. ¿Significa lo mismo en todos los contextos comunes?**

En esencia sí, sin embargo es demasiado amplio.

Referencia

- [¿Cuál es el proceso para eliminar las etiquetas (quemarlas)?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2839/65)